# When comparing child values(.val) for a Firebase Realtime Database Rule, how broad can the comparison be?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
"peopleWhoLike" : {
    ".write": "data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()"
  }
```

Below is the JSON structure. I want to be sure that it is checking the domain of the user writing = the domain of the user he writes to. For ease of understanding in the JSON structure, I made an example in bold at 3 spots **.

`IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1` is the user who want to write. He want to like and write to user uid. As a check, the domain of user uid and `IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1` are to be compared. Does the rule in the first line of my question do this, or would that only work for a different database structure?

```
    "people" : {
    “user uid” : {
      “**Domain** : "aol.com",
      "peopleWhoLike: {
        "-M-vZavBdcpX3SzkvgKN" : "**IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1**", ////this is autokey: uid of the likeR///
    }
   }
      “user uid1///IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1” : {
      “**Domain** : "aol.com",
      "peopleWhoLike: {
        "-M-htrhrthrdyhrf" : "tydBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1",
    }
   }
   “user uid2” : {
      “Domain : "yahoo.com",
      "peopleWhoLike: {
        "-M-gdgertghd" : "gertgerdgherdhedebe",
    }
   }
}
```

Update after answer

The code defines peopleWhoLike like this:

```
let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid] 
ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite some issues with the example. I'll point out the ones that jump out to me below:

1. These rules

   ```
   "peopleWhoLike" : {
     ".write": "data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()"
   }
   ```

   These now apply to the entire `peopleWhoLike`, where it seems you want to apply them to each individual like node under there, which would be:

   ```
   "peopleWhoLike" : {
     "$liker":
       ".write": "data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()"
     }
   }
   ```
2. The `newData.child('domain').val()` in your rules checks refers to a non-existing `domain` node under the liker. My guess is that you're trying to look up the data for the liker from their user profile, which would require something like `data.parent().parent().parent().child(newData.val()).child('domain').val()`.
3. Why are you using push keys under `peopleWhoLike`? If each user can only like another user once (which is the most common implementation of likes), it is idiomatic to use the UID of the liker as the key of their node:

   ```
    "people": {
      "user uid": {
        "Domain": "aol.com",
        "peopleWhoLike": {
          "IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1": true
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   With this structure you're automatically guaranteed that each user can only like each other user once, and it makes looking up the likes a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I'll answer 3 first. Multiple likes are allowed, but only on the following day. That is coded for (i.e the like doesn't register if the snapshot from the code determines a like was already made in today). Yeah to number 2. I'm surprised it allowed writes with the rule as is. I'll try yours there. For 1, where do you define "$liker". The code defines peopleWhoLike like this:   `let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid] ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff)`

Comment: #3) OK, #2) I'm not sure why that write would be allowed with out rules. But plesae don't post blocks of code in comments, and instead click the `edit` link under your question to add it there.

Comment: Will do. I'll post it in the question. The edit option for the comment has passed unfortunately.

Comment: Number 2 didn't work, which is weird cause the one I had right now did work. Shouldn't I use .validate there maybe. I think it is having trouble with $user uid, ie the `(newData.val())` part